# Calling a function from a function using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and some radio buttons on a page. Everytime my user selects an item on the dropdownbox
and the radio buttons are checked, I want the checked values of the radio buttons to be cleared. 
So I am calling a function in a change function but the radio buttons are not getting cleared.

please do you have an idea of what am doing wrong?

```
    $('#ddlCustomerNumber').change(function () {

            ClearFromOnDropDownChange();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PopulateTextBoxes", "Home")',
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    "customerId": $(this).val(),
                    "Country": $("#divcountry").text().trim()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var vdata = data;
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            $("#Csr").val(data[x].Csr);
                            $("#CustomerName").val(data[x].CustomerName);
                            $("#Address").val(data[x].Address);
                            $("#TelePhone").val(data[x].Telephone);
                            $("#Contact").val(data[x].Contact);
                            $("#AccountListId").val(data[x].AccountListId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });


        function ClearFromODropDownChange() {
            $("input:radio[name='1']:checked").val("");
            $("input:radio[name='2']:checked").val("");
            $("input:radio[name='3']:checked").val("");
            $("#yoo").val("");

        }
```

Here is the html

```
    <ol id="RowTwoQuestions">
            <li>
                <span>Were Billing adjustments made?</span>
                <input type="radio" name="1" value="Yes" id="g1yes" /><label for="g1yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="1" value="No" id="g1no" /><label for="g1no">No</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Which direction was billing adjusted?</span>
                <input type="radio" name="2" value="Up" id="g2up" /><label for="g2up">Up</label>
                <input type="radio" name="2" value="Down" id="g2down" /><label for="g2down">Down</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Was inventory returned?</span>
                <input type="radio" name="3" value="Yes" id="g3yes" /><label for="g3yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="3" value="No" id="g3no" /><label for="g3no">No</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Date customer inventory completed?</span>
                @Html.TextBox("CustInventory", null, new { @id = "yoo", @class = "datepicker" })
            </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Try `$("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it` as opposed to `$("input:radio[name='1']:checked").val("");` for clearing

Comment: Thanks a lot. $("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', false); works very well for me.

Comment: Props to the other guy who noted: `input[type=radio]` Changed in mine. Group hug guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [worked Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjg0ge9w/) :

**JS :**

Replace :

```
  function ClearFromODropDownChange() {
```

By :

```
  function ClearFromOnDropDownChange() { // add the (n) to OnDrop
```

AND Replce :

```
  $("input:radio[name='1']:checked").val("");
  $("input:radio[name='2']:checked").val("");
  $("input:radio[name='3']:checked").val("");
```

By :

```
$("input:radio[name='1']:checked").prop('checked', false);
$("input:radio[name='2']:checked").prop('checked', false);
$("input:radio[name='3']:checked").prop('checked', false);
```

Using jquery `.prop()` function to uncheck all checked inputs.

Hope that will help.